# Write the SQL code to find the average charge by the family medicine physicians

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

We need to write the script to find the average charge of physicians who specialize in "family medicine.

But i'm confused on how to write this because when we look at the appointment table, where we find the appointment_charge, it only gives us the physician_ID. How to link that to the specialize table.
Can anyone help me solve this problem?

This link below contains the diagram, tables and question. I am stuck at number 13. Take a look, it will make more sense :) >>>>

https://www.urgenthomework.com/question/hlst-3320-health-database-applications-sql-assignment

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Please provide us with the DDL and DML required from the script - use dbfiddle.uk... Seeing as this is some sort of assignment, can you show your first efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 tables you need to accomplish this:
Appointment Table, Physician table and little bit of the Specialization table (but just enough to know that the Family Medicine specialization has an specialization ID of 100).
This means your sql is:

```
select avg(a.appointment_charge) as AvgCharge
from appointment a inner join p on a.physician_id=p.physician_id
where p.specialization_id=100
```